# Census badge for answering 2018 Developer Survey is awarded only in one of the sites?

Tags: discussion, badges

I answered the Stack Overflow Developer Survey 2018 and was advised to expect a [census badge](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/6644/census) in [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). That makes sense because the link I followed was on that site, but:

as long as the survey is in English and both sites are totally related, just in different languages, shouldn't this badge be awarded in both sites, or just in the original [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?

Comment: Yeah, the [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/01/08/take-2018-developer-survey/?cb=1) makes it seem like it should have been (to all SE sites at that): "Users who complete the survey will be awarded the Census badge across any SE communities they belong to."

Comment: What happens if completed twice, following different links?

Comment: @Cœur IMHO answering twice survey will give fake results, but I don't know if you can open both links and answer later because link has dissapeared now from all sites

Comment: I didn't even know there are different platforms for different languages. For me, StackOverflow is only in english available. What is the domain for other languages?

Comment: @DanFromGermany They are [Spanish](http://es.stackoverflow.com), [Portuguese](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) and [Russian](http://ru.stackoverflow.com)

Comment: @DanFromGermany And [ja.so] (Japanese).

Comment: @DanFromGermany Visit [Do posts have to be in English on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/13676) to see list of sites for other languages.

Comment: it seems you cannot answer twice the survey, into the portuguese site I see the link, but if I click on it i get a msg: `You have either already completed the survey or your session has expired.`....

Comment: I think, I didn't get the badge at all :-/